# How to create a file in the documents folder if one doesn't exist?

Tags: swift, file-handling

I have the following code which writes to the end of a file.  However, how do I modify the behaviour so that it creates "output.txt" if it doesn't exist?

Thanks in advance!

```
func writeFile(){

    let str = "\n" + nominationKeyForWhenCellSelected! + "," + "1"
    let datafromString = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("output.txt")


    do {
        let fileHandle = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: filename)
        fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
        fileHandle.write(datafromString!)

    } catch {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use FileManager to check if the file exists or not. If not, simply write the data, otherwise append as you are doing. But don't forget to close the file handle.

```
do {
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filename.path) {
        let fileHandle = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: filename)
        fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
        fileHandle.write(datafromString!)
        fileHandle.closeFile()
    } else {
        datafromString.write(to: filename)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  Will test shortly.

Comment: Worked fine. I had to change filename to a string as it was being stored as a url, but it then worked fine.  Thanks!

Comment: I just updated the answer based on `filename` being a `URL`. I mistakenly thought it was a `String` when I first answered. It's better if it's a `URL`.

Comment: I did exactly that in the final code.... filename.path.  Worked like a charm!  Thank you again!